# Finding the matrix of a specific scalar product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

> Let $V$ be the vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ whose basis is $(\sin(t),\cos(t))$. Let the scalar product be defined by $$\langle f,g \rangle =\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)g(t)\,\mathrm dt$$ What is the matrix of this scalar product with respect to the given basis?

$$\langle f,g \rangle = \int_\limits{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t)g(t)\,\mathrm dt = \int_\limits{-\pi}^{\pi}(\sin (t)+\cos(t))(\sin (t)+\cos(t))\,\mathrm dt = 2\pi$$

From a previous exercise with polynomials, I acquired this method. However I do not get a matrix but a number. Am I doing anything wrong? I do not know why people consider it a duplicate, if I am not getting the same result using the same method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is almost identical to your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2368876/339790).

Comment: Homework is due tomorrow and you haven't done anything, huh.

Comment: $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \begin{bmatrix} \cos^2 (t) & \sin (t) \cos (t)\\ \sin (t) \cos (t) & \sin^2 (t)\end{bmatrix} \,\mathrm dt$$

Comment: @uniquesolution I am self-studying.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo How did you get that matrix?

Comment: @PedroGomes Let $$\mathrm v (t) := \begin{bmatrix} \cos (t) \\ \sin (t)\end{bmatrix}$$ and do what I did in my answer to your previous question.

Comment: I did the same but I got the above integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have not understood what the matrix of a scalar product with respect to a given basis is (even if there were some answers on your previous question), so let me make a general (not truly general but more general) remark on this. Given any $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $V$, say of dimension $n$, with scalar product \begin{align*}⟨ \; , \; ⟩ \colon V \times V &\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}, \\ (v,w) &\longmapsto ⟨v,w⟩, \end{align*} and basis $\mathcal{B}=(v_1, \dots , v_n)$, the matrix of the given scalar product with respect to $\mathcal{B}$ is given by \begin{align*} M_{\mathcal{B}}(⟨ \; , \; ⟩) = (⟨v_i,v_j⟩)_{ij}. \end{align*} Here you can see what you have to compute and where to fill in to get the matrix you are searching for.

Comment: I think I got the answer after understanding your comment. $\begin{bmatrix}\pi&2\pi\\2\pi&pi\end{bmatrix}$. I guess an application would make things clear and I created my own example $ \int_\limits{-\pi}^{\pi}(5\sin (t)+6\cos(t))(8\sin (t)+12\cos(t))\ dt$ Then I computed the result in the following way $\begin{bmatrix}5&6\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\pi&2\pi\\2\pi&pi\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}8\\12\end{bmatrix}$. However I do not know if I am proceeding well.

Comment: Apparently the integral $\int_\limits{-\pi}^{\pi}(5\sin (t)+6\cos(t))(8\sin (t)+12\cos(t))\ dt=112\pi$. But $\begin{bmatrix}5&6\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\pi&2\pi\\2\pi&pi\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}8\\12\end{bmatrix}
=328\pi$. Is it not supposed the result to be the same?

Comment: Your matrix is wrong. (But I guess you have found out what the mistake is?)

Comment: I did. $\begin{bmatrix}5&6\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\pi&0\\0&\pi\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}8\\12\end{bmatrix}$